# print 1, 2 1, 3 2 1, 4 3 2 1 side pyramid in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that will print

```
1
2 1
3 2 1
4 3 2 1
```

etc, in C, up to 20. I can get it to print

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

just fine.
Help?
This is what I have so far.

```
int i, j;
for(i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
  for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {
    printf("%3d", j); 
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply reverse your second loop to go from the higher number to the lower number like such:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
  for(j=i; j>0; j--) {
    printf("%3d", j); 
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

This will start with printing the largest number and end with a one.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for(j=1; j<=i; j++)` you are starting j at `1` and counting up until it reaches `i`. What you want to do ois start from `i` and count down (`--`) until it reaches `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you second for loop to `for(j=i;j>=1;j--)`.
It will print

```
 1
 2 1
 3 2 1
 4 3 2 1 and so on...
```

I hope this is what you asked..